# Recovering current user on Sharepoint 2010, angular version 6

Tags: angular, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I'm trying to recover the current user on a Sharepoint App inside Sharepoint server, It works in an old app I've tested here builded on AngularJS.

The code on AngularJS app is like this code below

```
var thisUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Title",
    debug: false
});
```

Now I'm trying to use the same code in Angular version 6, but when I try to build the project using this code. An error is accused

```
ERROR in src/app/pedido/pedido.component.ts(68,43): error TS2339:
Property 'SPGetCurrentUser' does not exist on type '(options?: any) => any'.
```

I've added the lib of SPServices on my angular.json, and on my `src/` folder, I've the file `typings.d.ts` with the content below

```
interface JQuery {
    SPServices(options?: any): any;
    SPFilterNode(options?: any): any;
    SPGetCurrentUser(options?: any): any;
}
```

Using this interface I can build other projects, just this one that tries to access the property `SPGetCurrentUser` in the `SPServices` don't let me build my project, what I can do to solve this?

On my `pedido.component.ts` I've declared the `$`, like the example below

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

It worked in all other projects, only in this one that doesn't...

I'm using this [lib](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPGetCurrentUser.html) from `sympmarc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend here found a solution to this problem, He changed the content in `typings.d.ts` to the example below

```
interface JQuery {
    //SPServices?(options?: any): any; // This line was removed
    SPServices: any; // This line was added 
    // Now the property SPGetCurrentUser can be viewed in the SPServices
    SPFilterNode(options?: any): any;
}
```